# Promise.all not working with asynchronous inner function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, es6-promise

I have a list of items (dishes) that i need to get the owners of each item(dish) from mongodb. I am using promises to execute this like so

```
 Dish.find({})
    .limit(lim)
    .sort({created : 1})
    .exec()
    .then(function(dishes){
        if (!dishes) {
            return next(new errors.ResourceNotFoundError('The resource you requested could not be found.'))
            next()
        }

        return dishOwners.getOwners(dishes)
    })
    .then(function(data){
        return res.send(200, data)
        next()
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        return next(new errors.InternalError(err.message))
        next()
    })
```

The dishOwners.getOwners(dishes) function returns a Promise.all that takes all the dishes like so

```
module.exports.getOwners = function(dishes){

return Promise.all(dishes.map(function(dish){
    User
      .findOne({_id:dish.created_by})
      .then(function(user){
           return {
             dish: dish,
             owner: user
           }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
          log.error(err.message)
      })
  }))
 }
```

The Problem is that

```
    return res.send(200, data)
    next()
```

gets called before Promise.all gets resolved and therefore returns null, from the way i know promise.all works that should not be the case.

Quiet new to promises, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why are you using promises first of all?

Comment: Alravind alterrnatives?

Comment: `Observables` are alternatives for it

Comment: would be great if you could show a way to chain requests like promises with observables. if you have a link to a tutorial would be great.

Comment: I can help you with your scenario but I dont have a tutorial or link. create a plunker for your code i will help you to fix it

Comment: ok...will hit u up with a plunker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149907/discussion-between-joshua-majebi-and-aravind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a return statement in `getOwners`. Your code should be:

```
module.exports.getOwners = function(dishes){

return Promise.all(dishes.map(function(dish){
    return User
      .findOne({_id:dish.created_by})
      .then(function(user){
           return {
             dish: dish,
             owner: user
           }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
          log.error(err.message)
      })
  }))
}
```

Because of this mistake, you're passing `Promise.all` an array of `undefined` values, so it resolves immediately.